# Fetching compute_networks from project using data resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to find a way to fetch all `google_compute_network` from a given project in Terraform. Is this possible to do?

Version: Terraform v0.11.13

From the documentation, I see that the [network data resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_compute_network.html): `google_compute_network` requires the name of the network to be supplied. But what I'm looking for is a way to get a list of networks from a specific project.

I require this because I intend to add all the networks of a project to `private_visibility_config` for a Private DNS Managed Zone resource. There are multiple projects I want to do this to. The number of networks in each is arbitrary and so are the names of the networks.

What I'd like to be able to do:

```
resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "private-zone" {
  name = "${var.project_id}-private-zone"
  dns_name = "private.example.local."
  description = "test"

  visibility = "private"

  private_visibility_config {
    networks {
    //SOME INTERPOLATION HERE
    }
  }
}

// Something like this
data "google_compute_network" "project-1" {
  project = "${var.project_id}"
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The usual way this is supported is for the provider to offer a separate plural data resource type alongside the singular one, as we see in e.g. the AWS provider with `aws_vpcs` vs. `aws_vpc`. The GCP provider doesn't seem to offer such a thing, so I think you'd need to open a feature request for this for something like `google_compute_networks`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinAtkins, I'll do that.